# dplyr everything() argument string select_

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyselect

I need to use the underscored string version of `select` in `dplyr` along with the `everything()` argument. It is not working.

```
library(dplyr)
#this works just fine
select(iris, Species, everything()) %>% head()

  Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1  setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2  setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3  setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4  setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5  setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
6  setosa          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4

#this fails
select_(iris, "Species", everything()) %>% head()
```

> Error: No tidyselect variables were registered

Is there an underscored argument of `everything` which I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_` method is getting deprecated.  Instead, we can use `sym` from `rlang` to convert it to symbol and then evaluate

```
library(dplyr)
select(iris, !!rlang::sym("Species"), everything()) %>%
          head()
#     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1  setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
#2  setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
#3  setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
#4  setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
#5  setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
#6  setosa          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

Comment: I figured this might end up being my introduction into the `bang bang!!`. Thank you!